# Confusion about the reshape function in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

This will be a messy question with a lot of code but you need the context in order to understand the problem.
So I am starting to learn OpenCV and I ran into a problem with understanding something. The code works perfectly but I don't know how it works.
So I'm following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) post and it is quite good. Just one line at the end of the post confuses me. It's the line number 62. I understand why is the `screenCnt` multiplied by `ratio` but what is the purpose of the `reshape` function there. And what does it really do? I couldn't find documentation that I could understand.
In order to understand my question look at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) post too.

Answer (score 2):

He needs to reshape because `screenCnt` is an `np-array` produced by `approxPolyDP` so it's <strike>the transpose</strike> a different matrix of what the `four_point_transform` function accepts as parameter `pts`. Essentially `pts` should be a 4x2 matrix and `screenCnt` is 2x4 so he has to reshape.

**edit:** I run the commands on a different image and it seems that `screenCnt` has 4 elements of type `[[num1,num2]]` whereas `pts` elements should be `[num1,num2]`. That's what reshape on that particular case accomplishes. My answer is correct for the general use of the `reshape` function.

Comment: The right answer, though 'transpose' is a bit misleading as it has a defined meaning for matrices. reshape() just changes the number of columns and rows the matrix has while keeping the same data in the same memory order. Think of it as "word wrap" for matrices.

Comment: Thanks I corrected my answer, I think it's more accurate now.